# How to add a gradient color to an icon with no border

Tags: css, sass, hover, icons, gradient

I would like to make a like icon and I would like to entierely fill an icon with gradient color in hover with no border only the heart shape. i use fontawesome.

html:

```
                    <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
```

sass:

```
        i{
        position: absolute;
        left: 70vmin;
        top:2vmin;
        font-size: 1.6em;
        z-index: 100;
        cursor: pointer;
        font-weight: 100;
        &:hover{
            transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
            -webkit-background-clip: text;
            font-weight: 900;
            background-image: linear-gradient($color-primary, $color-secondary);
            -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
        }
```

I saw a lot of people who use background-clip and text-fill-color but the icon disapear only.

Is there any solution?

Thanks

Comment: please add css not sass

Comment: make sure you are using the CSS verion of font awesome and not the SVG/JS one

Comment: After checking I am using the css version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve like it:

```css
i{
  position: absolute;
  left: 70vmin;
  top:2vmin;
  font-size: 1.6em;
  z-index: 100;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 100;
}   
i:hover:before{
  transition: all .8s ease-in-out;
  -webkit-background-clip: text;
  font-weight: 900;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, yellow);
  -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pro.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.10.0/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-AYmEC3Yw5cVb3ZcuHtOA93w35dYTsvhLPVnYs9eStHfGJvOvKxVfELGroGkvsg+p" crossorigin="anonymous"/>
<i class="far fa-heart"></i>
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer. Is there any solution for the  black border? I would like it to disapear and that only the shape of the heart remains

Comment: your update of the question create a *working* code, you should not do such edit because you don't know how the OP is including the library and in the question he said *no border*

Comment: @TemaniAfif next time, i will take of this

Comment: @EdwinLandsfield so you did not need a black border on hover?

Comment: Yes that's it i don't need the black border on hover